# How can I filter graph ql query based on markdown frontmatter?

Tags: markdown, graphql, gatsby

I am setting up a folio site using Gatsby. My data is stored in markdown files and retrieved using graphql and the gatsby-transformer-remark plug in. I currently have 3 files, which I can successfully return in a Graph QL query:
[image]

However, I am doing something wrong when I try to filter them by type:
[image]

Many thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the `filter` should be on the `allMarkdownRemark`:

```
{
  allMarkdownRemark (
    filter: {
      frontmatter: { type: { eq: "folio" } }
    }
  ) {
    edges {
      node {
        frontmatter {
          title
          featured_image
          type
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter based on MardownRemark rather than allMarkdownRemark you can use this:
 [image]

or, if you want it to be dynamic like when you want to open a specific blog post from the list of posts in your blog, you can use this format: 
[image]